# Generating Python-version-dependent installer with pre-compiled extension package

Tags: python, installation, distutils

I am trying to create an installer (using distutils) for a Python package that includes a pre-compiled extension module which is included using the "package_data" keyword argument. My setup.py looks something like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name="Foobar",
      ...
      packages = ['Foobar'],
      package_data = {'Foobar': '_foobar.pyd'})
```

However, building this package with `python setup.py bdist_msi` generates an installer that will install for any version of Python (named `Foobar-1.0.win-amd64.msi`), even though the extension module is only compatible with the Python version it was compiled for.

Is there any way to tell distutils to create an installer that requires the compatible Python version, similar to what is produced when distutils is used to compile the extension module (producing an installer named `Foobar-1.0.win-amd64-py2.7.msi`)

So far, the best solution I've come up with is to include an additional (dummy) extension package, but that seems kind of kludgy and creates some additional problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `--target-version` argument, e.g.

```
python setup.py bdist_msi --target-version=2.7
```

The [Distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html) mentions this option in reference to the `bdist_rpm` command, but it also works for `bdist_msi`.